# Filter and copy certain rows from multiple excel sheets to another

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am using a workbook that has various sheets. I want to copy all the rows from the last 5 sheets that have the value "Pending" in their column "J". I want to create a new tab named "Pending week" and paste all these rows there. Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Also, is it always the last 5 sheets? What happens if a user re-arranges the sheets or adds/deletes sheets?

Comment: It is always the last 5 sheets @QHarr

Answer (score 1):

You can create this yourself very easily if you just break it down:

- Add a new Sheet
- Name the sheet to Pending Week
- Find the five latest sheets.
- Create some kind of loop that copy paste row if cells in column J contains the value "Pending"

You have not provided any code, so I'll give you a base to work from:

**You add a new sheet & name it using:**

```
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pending week"
```

**Find the five latest sheets**

To my knowledge, you can't find the latest sheets. Sheets doesn't contain the date and time of when they were created. But if we ignore that and expect the five latest sheets to be placed in the workbook to the far most right (Default position for newly created sheets). Then you need to figure out how many sheets you have and count backwards.

You can use: `Worksheets.Count` to count all the sheets. Use this number and count it backwards. My first thought would be to use a `For Loop`

```
Dim X As Integer
For X = (Worksheets.Count - 4) To Worksheets.Count

Next
```

`X` would be the identifier to find our latest sheets. So you should incorporate that into our loop below. You want to place the loop within this For Block.

**Loop**

There are many ways to find a value in a sheet, but you need to figure out what the last row of your sheets are. Without it we don't know when the code should stop.

You can use a `Do Until` Loop if there is a value in all J cells. Then you can simply insert the entire row into *Pending week*

It would look something like:

```
Dim XLrow As Integer
XLrow = 1

Do Until Worksheets(1).Cells(XLrow, "J") = ""

    If Worksheets(1).Cells(XLrow, "J") = "Pending" Then
        Worksheets(1).Range(XLrow & ":" & XLrow) = Worksheets("Pending week").Cells(XLrow, "J").Value
    End If

XLrow = XLrow + 1
Loop
```

You will need to change the Range to the length of the range you want to copy. *Note: the value Pending is case sensitive, so keep that in mind.*

Alright, this is what you need to create your code. Of course you need to change values to fit your own workbook, but this is the base.

Comment: OP has just added a sheet so last 5 would include the sheet they are trying to paste to wouldn't it? Maybe specify in the Add sheet part a before condition?

Comment: That's a good point, but it doesn't seem to work this way. `Worksheets.Add` adds the sheet on the most left side of the workbook. So it shouldn't affect the rest of the code. To secure this, we could use `Before:=Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Hello @EliasWick I would like to thank you for the answer. It is very well explained. First of all i want to take the values from the last 5 sheets i.e. the sheets placed at the right most only.  When i try to run your code, i reach the Do while loop and it skips the condition and goes to the next sheet directly. Can you please simulate once and correct it if necessary.

Comment: Could you update your post with the code you have written, so that I can see where it fails? :)

Comment: Dim X As Integer
Dim XLrow As Integer

Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pending week"

For X = (Worksheets.Count - 4) To Worksheets.Count

XLrow = 1

Do Until Worksheets(1).Cells(XLrow, "J") = ""

    If Worksheets(1).Cells(XLrow, "J") = "Pending" Then
        Worksheets(1).Range(XLrow & ":" & XLrow) = Worksheets("Pending week").Cells(XLrow, "J").Value
    End If

XLrow = XLrow + 1
Loop

Next

Comment: @EliasWick Please refer to the comment above

Comment: Could you add it into your original post and type it like this: `code`? It's very hard to read it like you have posted it.